# How to connect Sauna heater to dryer outlet using dryer extension cord

Tags: electrical, heater

I bought an electrical sauna heater that runs on 220v and I am planning to hook it up to a dryer extension cord - one end of cord into dryer socket (4 prong) and other end cut off and wired into heater power board. I’d appreciate some advise on which prongs from the dryer cord attach to which inputs on the heater. I’m pretty sure A and C on the plug/wire go to 2 and 3, but what about the ground connection? Do I use B or D?

[image]

[image]

Comment: D is ground.  B is neutral and and not used.  Should have a wire nut on the end of it.  Is this a European sauna on a North American electric system?

Comment: Thanks Crisp659! I bought the heater on Amazon. There is a clamp for the wire in the heater connection box.

Comment: @Kaigoss -- does the heater have a UL, ETL, or CSA (i.e. NRTL) listing and label/mark?

Comment: ThreePhaseEel: It says CE IPX4

Comment: @Kaigoss CE effectively means nothing and IPX4 is a water-resistance rating but not a guarantee of anything. **You should not use this thing. But if you must then use it on a GFCI breaker because it is just too dangerous otherwise.** But preferably don't use it at all. The risks are **HUGE**.